# QuickActionDefinition user permission

Tags: permissions, flow

I have a flow that needs to create a task through a Quick Action. When running the flow using the end-user profile, I receive an error that states the following:

```
sObject type 'QuickActionDefinition' is not supported.
```

I am assuming that this is a permission issue, as I can run through the flow (under the sys admin profile) with no problem. Where do I find the settings to allow the end-user profile access to this class?

Comment: What license is your "end-user"?  Is it a community license?  I too am running into this issue with a Login Flow that is used for Communities logins

Comment: It's a Salesforce license, not community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After opening a support ticket with Salesforce, it was determined that the profile of the user running the flow must have "Manage Force.com Flow" permission. This fixed the issue with all QuickActionDefinition permission issues.